# how ot create an index on a JSON String array in mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

how ot create an index on a JSON String array in mysql 8.0

the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued
Creating multi-valued Indexes demo only show me that create a num index
so. how to create a String array index
such as
create table tableDemo(
JSONDEMO JSON
)

{
"user":"Bob",
"user_id":31,
"zipcode":["string","i am String"]
}

i want to know how to write the create index statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to create a String array index such as create table

The example from the Reference Manual, modified:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
         id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         modified DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
         custinfo JSON
         );

INSERT INTO customers VALUES
        (NULL, NOW(), '{"user":"Jack","user_id":37,"zipcode":["194582","94536"]}'),
        (NULL, NOW(), '{"user":"Jill","user_id":22,"zipcode":["194568","94507","94582"]}'),
        (NULL, NOW(), '{"user":"Bob","user_id":31,"zipcode":["94477","94507"]}'),
        (NULL, NOW(), '{"user":"Mary","user_id":72,"zipcode":["194536"]}'),
        (NULL, NOW(), '{"user":"Ted","user_id":56,"zipcode":["94507","582"]}');
```

```
SELECT id, modified, CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE '94507' MEMBER OF(custinfo->'$.zipcode');
EXPLAIN SELECT id, modified, CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE '94507' MEMBER OF(custinfo->'$.zipcode');
```

| id | modified | CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Jill", "user_id": 22, "zipcode": ["194568", "94507", "94582"]} |
| 3 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Bob", "user_id": 31, "zipcode": ["94477", "94507"]} |
| 5 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Ted", "user_id": 56, "zipcode": ["94507", "582"]} |

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | customers | *null* | ALL | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 5 | 100.00 | Using where |

```
ALTER TABLE customers
    ADD INDEX zips( (CAST(custinfo->'$.zipcode' AS CHAR(8) ARRAY)) );
```

```
SELECT id, modified, CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE '94507' MEMBER OF(custinfo->'$.zipcode');
EXPLAIN SELECT id, modified, CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE '94507' MEMBER OF(custinfo->'$.zipcode');
```

| id | modified | CAST(custinfo AS CHAR) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Jill", "user_id": 22, "zipcode": ["194568", "94507", "94582"]} |
| 3 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Bob", "user_id": 31, "zipcode": ["94477", "94507"]} |
| 5 | 2023-11-30 07:55:07 | {"user": "Ted", "user_id": 56, "zipcode": ["94507", "582"]} |

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | customers | *null* | ref | zips | zips | 35 | const | 3 | 100.00 | Using where |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Iok4sE5_)

Pay attention - only fixed-length string (CHAR) can be used in multi-valued index, so VARCHAR or TEXT will result in error.

Also - the criteria value must be string too. If you use numeric value (`WHERE 94507 MEMBER OF(custinfo->'$.zipcode')`) then the output will be empty.

Comment: yes . i had create a JSON index likely what you write .
but when i try to select the array element with index . 
i found it slower than without index 
such as 
EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM table_with_index WHERE "tom" MEMBER OF(notice_users_json->'$.user')  limit 1000
EXPLAIN
SELECT a,b FROM table_without_index WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(notice_users, '["tom"]') limit 100

i have explain it had hit the index . but its slower. why .Confuse me

Comment: @ziliangzeng I think that your table is small and it is cached completely. In this case immediate table scan will be faster.

Comment: it have about 7000000 record .
i think my select statment have some problem

Comment: @ziliangzeng You must create another question - about the query improvement. Provide enough data in it - according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) #5, #3 and #4.